# How to get widths of all columns in a Tabulator table?

Tags: tabulator

Is there a way to get the width of all the columns?
I was experimenting with this:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    columnResized:function(column){
        var columns = table.getColumns()
        for (i = 0; i < columns.length; i++)
        {
            // columns[i].width isn't valid, is there something else that can be used?
        }
    },
});
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the entire column layout, use:

```js
var columns = table.getColumnLayout()
for (i = 0; i < columns.length; i++)
{
    columns[i].width = ... // or columns[i]["width"]
}
```